# How to Upload an Image using PHP REST API and REACT js using JSON format?

Tags: php, json, reactjs, api, file-upload

I have some perfectly working **PHP APIs** for basic **CRUD operations** where user can create, read, update and delete any form data. Now I want to **insert images** as well. I use **REACT for client side**.

So I want to modify my "create_product" php APIs so that it can accept the **JSON** **encoded data**(uploaded img) from user and insert it in Database. and Also the reverse action where it will Show the **image** of a product whenever Read API is called.

I **searched this alot** but they give other solutions but nor with **JSON** format or API. i know regular way to upload image in php but cannot figure it out in rest API.

PLEASE ANYONE HELP ME. I would be really THANKFUL. 
here is my **PHP API code**:

```js
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// files needed to connect to database
include_once 'config/database.php';
include_once 'objects/product.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// instantiate product object
$user = new Product($db);

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));


// make sure data is not empty
if(
!empty($data->Name) &&
!empty($data->Price) &&
!empty($data->Description) &&
!empty($data->VehicleID)
) {

    // set product property values
    $user->Name = $data->Name;
    $user->Price = $data->Price;
    $user->Warranty = $data->Warranty;
    $user->Description = $data->Description;
    $user->Status = $data->Status;

    $user->SubCatPartID = $data->SubCatPartID;
    $user->VehicleID = $data->VehicleID;
    $user->VendorID = $data->VendorID;


  
    if ($user->create()) {

        http_response_code(200);

        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Spare Part Record is inserted Successfully"));
    } 
    else {

        http_response_code(400);

        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to insert Spare Part... Sorry..."));
    }
}

else{
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create product. Data is EMPTY."));
}

?>
```

here is the php ***create()*** method:

```js
class Product{

    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "sparepart";

    // object properties
    public $SparePartID;
    public $Name;
    public $Price;
    public $Warranty;
    public $Description;
    public $Status;
    public $SubCatPartID;
    public $VehicleID;
    public $VendorID;


    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    function create(){

        // insert query
        $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                Name = :Name,
                Price = :Price,
                Warranty = :Warranty,
                Description = :Description,
                Status = :Status,
                SubCatPartID = :SubCatPartID,
                VehicleID = :VehicleID,
                VendorID = :VendorID";

        // prepare the query
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // sanitize
        $this->Name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->Name));
        $this->Price=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->Price));
        $this->Warranty=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->Warranty));
        $this->Description=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->Description));
        $this->Status=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->Status));

        $this->SubCatPartID=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->SubCatPartID));
        $this->VehicleID=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->VehicleID));

        $this->VendorID=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->VendorID));

        $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $this->Name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Price', $this->Price);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Warranty', $this->Warranty);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Description', $this->Description);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Status', $this->Status);
        $stmt->bindParam(':SubCatPartID', $this->SubCatPartID);
        $stmt->bindParam(':VehicleID', $this->VehicleID);
        $stmt->bindParam(':VendorID', $this->VendorID);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

And here is my API call in REACT JS (to create product):

```js
  onSubmit (e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    const sparepart = {
      Name: this.state.Name,
      Price: this.state.Price,
      Warranty: this.state.Warranty,
      Description: this.state.Description,
      Status: this.state.Status,
      SubCatPartID: this.state.SubCatPartID,
      VehicleID: this.state.VehicleID,

      VendorID: this.state.vendor.VendorID }


  axios.post('http://localhost/Auth/api/insert_parts.php', sparepart)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data);
    alert("Congratulations! New Spare Part has been added!");
    this.setState({redirectToReferrer: true});
    return result;
   })
   .catch(error => {
   if (error) {
     console.log("Sorry cannot insert data");
   console.log(error);  }
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PHP is not great, so I'll try to explain my answer thoroughly since I can't give an example. In React, you can use an `input` tag with `type="file"` to accept images and set it to the React component's state. Once done, you can use the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) class to read the file and have return a Base64 string. Then all you have to do is add another tag in your current JSON  input for the string and send it along all at once! Make sure to allow multipart in PHP since the image might be too big for one packet.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. I did the same as u told. now my react is sending a base64 in string format to the php server. I followed so many links on how to save that fetched "base64" image into the DB server using php. All say to decode it and replace  spaces like this $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));


$Img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data->Image);
$Img = str_replace(' ', '+', $Img);

$Img = base64_decode($Img); I did it same but it doesnt do anything and saves nothing in my DB. Also gives no Error. PLease help me.

Comment: A Base64 string is just that, it's just a string. You have to store it in your DB as a string. If you were grabbing the image as a file, it would have to be saved as a blob. You're trying to Base64 decode the image before storing it into your DB, which throws an error since databases are not for storing data as files.